# How can I group functions together

Tags: actionscript-2, flash-cs4

I have created an image map with flash, I have separate button functions that display rollover and onpress functions for each region ie -

```
nw_btn.onRollOver = function() {
   areaName_txt.text = "This Site (NWPHO)";
}

nw_btn.onPress = function() {
   displayOverlay(areaName_txt.text);
}
```

This is repeated 15 times to cover each area button - I wondered whether there was a way to apply the same function call (displayOverlay) and apply area name text on rollover via one piece of code rather than repeating for each button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there must be a mistake with your tag, because what you describe look more like an AS2 structure.

But if you really are in AS3, here is what you can do : connect everything to a same function with addEventListener. In this function, test which button is at the source of the event, then put the code to be executed for each button.

Comment: thanks, sorry its been over a year since I even looked at Flash - you've put me on the right track, works a treat.  cheers